# Read multiple excels file from a path with Python Tkinter and Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

How to read multiple files with tkinter?

My code

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
import tkinter
from tkinter import messagebox
import os
import pandas as pd 
import tkinter.font as tkFont
import numpy as np 
import warnings


top = tkinter.Tk()
top.title('Interface')
top.resizable(True, True)

# Defines the GUI interface
top.geometry('1000x350')
L1 = Label(top, text="Choose woorksheet")
L1.grid(column=0, row=5, padx=10, pady=10)
E1 = Entry(top, bd=5, width=70)
E1.grid(row=5, column=1, pady=10)

def findpath():
    f = fd.askdirectory()
    E1.insert(0, f)


def trying():

    folder = E1.get()
    base_info_cambio = pd.read_excel(folder + r'\INFO_1.xlsx')


    base_info_cliente = pd.read_excel(folder + r'INFO_2.xlsx')

btnTrying = Button(top, text='  Find   ', command= findpath, height=1)
btnTrying.grid(row=7,column=3, pady=25, )

btnTrying = Button(top, text='   Read ', command= trying, height=1)
btnTrying.grid(row=8,column=3, pady=25, )

top.mainloop()
```

This gives me the error "**FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:**" when I try to read some data.

Could you please help me? How can I define the worksheets path dynamically? I want to pass the folder and the files will be always the same, so I need only to write the folder path and my code will have the file names inplace.

Comment: There may be missing "\" between `folder` and `INFO_2.xlsx`.  Better use `os.path.join(folder, 'INFO_2.xlsx')` instead.

Comment: maybe use `print()` to see what path you created. And later you can check if this path really exists. And if this is relative path then it may not work if code run in wrong folder. First try with absolute path.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.